# Need to Automate WebApplication includes OTP for login

Tags: c#, selenium-webdriver

Have a web application where as soon as I enter UserName i will get OTP in my email. I am not getting the way how to automate using Selenium C# this OTP scenario so that scripts should run in CI as well.

Saw the solution but those are good if running scripts in local machine but when overnight scripts run in build this solution won't help

Any lead will be highly appreciated..

Thanks in Advance

Comment: What do you mean by OTP? One time password?

Comment: Unclear. Describe a bit more the OTP. What  is "the solution" you saw? Do you have a link for this solution maybe it's clearer there? [Ask], proof read the question like you don't know the issue.

Answer (score 0):

If your OTP also generates in DB then fetch the OTP from DB.

Another way developer can provide you an API which will have OTP key:value.

Third way open email using selenium, read the OTP and navigate to your test application

Comment: We are using 3rd party tool for Authentication and they won't expose their database tables to us. Getting OTP from an email is fine as long as we are running scripts in our local machine but if we have to execute them using Jenkins  [build] getting otp from email is not possible.